# How to convert Beautiful Soup 4 Tag objects into a String?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, casting

I'm pretty new to web-scraping, and I am parsing through an XML file with Beautiful Soup 4. I want to pull the string form of the urls that are encompassed by the link tag: < link> https://www.whateveriwant.com < link>.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
bs_content = bs(content, "lxml") # content is an entire XML file in one string
bsUrlsList = bs_content.find_all("link")  # gets all urls, fills a list with bs4 tag objs
```

The problem is when I iterate through bsUrlsList and print each item, it prints a list of [,], as opposed to the actual string version of the link.

```
for link in bsUrlsList:
  print(type(link)) # prints <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

**Big Question**: How do I convert <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> to a String so that I can eventually have a list of string urls that I pulled from the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
goal = list(soup.select("link").strings)
```

Or

```
goal = [x.text for x in soup.findAll("link")]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This solution returned a list of empty strings. 
Here is a test XML file where I am pulling the links from: https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en
how can I pull the string version of the link from this?